# Изменение картинки при наведении WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Приветствую!

Есть WPF приложение, на одной из форм которого расположена картинка:

```
<Image Width="30" Height="30" Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/reminder.png" >
```

Вопрос - как наиболее простым способом реализовать поведение, при котором если курсор наведен на картинку то `Source` картинки изменится на `"pack://application:,,,/Resources/reminder2.png"`а при отведении обратно ?

Можно написать тригеры, добавить в вьюмодели свойство `string Patch= "pack://...";` затем вызвать `NotifyPropertyChanged`... Но наверняка это можно реализовать гораздо проще. Если можно, то как? Ограничиваясь только средствами разметки (+ расширения XAML) такое воплотить ?

UPD 
Код :

```
<Image Width="30" Height="30" Visibility="{Binding FileOkVisible, Converter={StaticResource B2V}}"
       Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/reminder.png" Cursor="Hand">
    <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="pack://application:,,,/Resources/reminder_Delet.png"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Source" Value="pack://application:,,,/Resources/reminder.png"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

Пути до файлов прописаны верно, однако ничего не происходит. В чем ошибка ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Разобрался. Если кому понадобится менять картинку при наведении в WPF реализовать это можно так :

```
<Image Width="30" Height="30" Visibility="{Binding FileOkVisible, Converter={StaticResource B2V}}"
       Cursor="Hand">
    <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="pack://application:,,,/Resources/reminder_Delet.png"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="pack://application:,,,/Resources/reminder.png"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

Comment: Можно немного проще: https://pastebin.com/DuHUA1jm