# Смена картинки при наведении на кнопку

Tags: c#, wpf, button

Имеется такая кнопка:

```
<Button x:Name="btnVK" Margin="0,117,953,582" RenderTransformOrigin="0.567,0.409" Click="imgBtn1_Click" Foreground="{x:Null}" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
    <Image Source="Images/vk@3x.png" Stretch="Fill" IsEnabled="False" Width="36" Height="36" />
</Button>
```

Как сделать так чтобы при наведении `Image Source=""` менялся на другое изображение. Пытался писать стили, но ничего не вышло.

UPD: Если создаю `<ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">`, то это отражается на всех кнопках.

Comment: `<ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">` - указывайте `Key="MyStyle"` и не будет на все кнопки. В нужной всего лишь указываете `Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}"`.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Изменение картинки при наведении WPF](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/728917/%d0%98%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-wpf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Source" Value="pack://application:,,,/Resources/reminder_Delet.png"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Source" Value="pack://application:,,,/Resources/reminder.png"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
```

Взято [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/728917/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-wpf?rq=1)